# Can I use Spring Framework with swing/SWT?

Tags: java, spring

I want to develop a Desktop Application, so I have choice for UI development (Swing or SWT) but I want to know that can I use Spring with one of them? Also I want to use eclipse IDE and java 1.6 for development, is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want to use Spring?

Answer (score 1):

Spring is a big framework. Which parts of it do you want to use? If you are referencing to the IOC, AOP, JDBCTemplate, then yes definitely you can use it in any application provided that you include the jar files correctly.

You will need to load the applicationContext.xml using `ClassPathResouce`.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I want to refer Spring's IOC, AOP and Hibernate also I am looking to integrate RMI for internal messaging, is it possible?

Comment: @Balasaheb: Yes, it's possible. (Whether it's advisable is a separate matter, but that's nothing to do with Spring and everything to do with overall application architecture. Totally out of scope of this question!)